# Jquery getJSON Not Working Cross Site

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I have a piece of javascript that grabs JSON data. When executed locally everything seems to work fine. However, when I try accessing it from a different site, it doesn't work.

Here's the script.

```
$(function(){
    var aT = new AjaxTest();
    aT.getJson();
});

var AjaxTest = function()
{
    this.ajaxUrl = "http://mydeveloperpage.com/sandbox/ajax_json_test/client_reciever.php";

    this.getJson = function(){
        $.getJSON(this.ajaxUrl, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, piece){
                alert(piece);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You can find a copy of the exact same file at "http://mydeveloperpage.com/sandbox/ajax_json_test/".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> - Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; **the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.**
> - Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

You're going to need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to get past the same-origin policy. jQuery can make this seamless (see the rest of the aforementioned documentation page).