# Why is this failing in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

My website fails in IE.  I only have access to Macs so it's hard to test and parallels is meh.  I have been able to check once or twice so I know it fails when it searches youtube.

Close the popup > Hit 2010 > Hit 10/20 > Hit My Soul > Error

http://www.phishvid.com/

Could anyone provide some insight? Here's the code where it fails:

Thanks!

Comment: which version of IE? things involving JS often fail on IE <=7 or <=6 cause of different versions of MS's interpretation of the standard

Comment: I believe all of them.  I'm really unable to test it well. Do you think you could check really quick? Thanks.

Comment: This is a cross-site scripting issue, IE is likely blocking the ajax/json request. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038862/jquery-getjson-not-working-cross-site/3038886#3038886

Comment: I've honestly tried jsonp 50 times and spent hours and could never get it working with youtube (at least to retrieve the youtube link/id).  Do you think you could show me how it works?

Comment: Well , i tried the above mentioned steps in IE 7 and got a js error "Access is denied" , guess as Craig pointed out , it is due to cross-site scripting

Comment: can you add a proper doctype to your page, as it is rendered in `Quirks Mode`. You can use the simple HTML5 Doctype - `<!doctype html>`

Comment: I don't often give out upvotes for stupid reasons but +1 for Phish

Comment: Seriously, that is an awesome website. I would highly recommend not making missing songs look like links though. There are few things that will make me agro faster than thinking I'm gonna get to hear antelope and than not hearing it. Know what I mean?

Comment: Haha yeah. I'm working on a database. As of right now (as you can see) it just pulls it from YouTube, but soon it will store URLs and I'll be able to do that! Hence the beta. Share with your friends!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to make an AJAX request to a different domain, which is being restricted by the `Same Origin Policy`.

To over come this use JSONP, to make your request use JSONP `callback=?` to the url that your requesting, this will help you overcome the cross-domain barrier.

You updated url should look like

```
 $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?callback=?&max-results=5&alt=json&q=phish " + song + " " + month2 + " " + day + " " + year, function (data) {
   //your callback code
 }
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/uluci3/3)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212105/how-to-get-and-display-the-list-of-youtube-videos-using-javascript  for some more help on this

Comment: This seems to work! I thought I tried this, but I guess not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My IE reports "Access is denied" in jquery-1.4.4.min.js on line 138, char 355 which on your site looks like this:

```
if(w){b.username?w.open(h,b.url,b.async,b.username,b.password):w.open(h,b.url,b.async);try{if(b.data!=null&&!l||a&&a.contentType)w.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
b.contentType);if(b.ifModified){c.lastModified[b.url]&&w.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since",c.lastModified[b.url]);c.etag[b.url]&&w.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match",c.etag[b.url])}o||w.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");w.setRequestHeader("Accept",b.dataType&&b.accepts[b.dataType]?b.accepts[b.dataType]+", */*; q=0.01":b.accepts._default)}catch(I){}if(b.beforeSend&&b.beforeSend.call(b.context,w,b)===false){b.global&&c.active--===1&&c.event.trigger("ajaxStop");w.abort();return false}b.global&&
c.triggerGlobal(b,"ajaxSend",[w,b]);var L=w.onreadystatechange=function(m){if(!w||w.readyState===0||m==="abort"){J||c.handleComplete(b,w,e,f);J=true;if(w)w.onreadystatechange=c.noop}else if(!J&&w&&(w.readyState===4||m==="timeout")){J=true;w.onreadystatechange=c.noop;e=m==="timeout"?"timeout":!c.httpSuccess(w)?"error":b.ifModified&&c.httpNotModified(w,b.url)?"notmodified":"success";var p;if(e==="success")try{f=c.httpData(w,b.dataType,b)}catch(q){e="parsererror";p=q}if(e==="success"||e==="notmodified")d||
c.handleSuccess(b,w,e,f);else c.handleError(b,w,e,p);d||c.handleComplete(b,w,e,f);m==="timeout"&&w.abort();if(b.async)w=null}};try{var g=w.abort;w.abort=function(){w&&Function.prototype.call.call(g,w);L("abort")}}catch(i){}b.async&&b.timeout>0&&setTimeout(function(){w&&!J&&L("timeout")},b.timeout);try{w.send(l||b.data==null?null:b.data)}catch(n){c.handleError(b,w,null,n);c.handleComplete(b,w,e,f)}b.async||L();return w}
```

the actual character number 355 is the first b, so I'm guessing you might have come across a bug in jQuery 1.4.4? you could try to either use a previous version (unless you are using some 1.4.4 specific features) or replace the .min.js file with the full jquery file, insert a debugger-statement into the jquery-file at this location (before it throws the exception) and try to debug to figure out what is wrong. You can for instance use Microsoft Visual Web developer to debug, or if the same issue occurs in IE9 it has a built in .js - debugger as well

EDIT: after seeing the full jQuery code you posted it is clear that the problem is that jQuery in this case is trying a standard ajax call, not JSONP. (standard ajax only allowed back to the server which served the javascript)

Comment: Can you check it here? http://phishvid.com/index2.html that's the development version.

Comment: You see the line "xhr.open" (line 5910 in your jquery.js) it means jQuery is doing standard ajax calls, (not jsonp), which is not allowed under same origin policy. what you could do is to make an ajax-call down to a web service or page or whatever on your own server, have the server perform an http request to get the stuff from youtube and then send it back to the client