# jQuery AJAX getJSON() Method example isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I took this code straight from the w3 schools example, however, outside of their "Tryit Editor" it doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.getJSON("http://w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js", function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                        $("div").append(field + " ");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Get JSON data</button>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to [avoid using w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Comment: **`->`** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy **`<-`**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery getJSON Not Working Cross Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038862/jquery-getjson-not-working-cross-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only make an AJAX request to a location on the current domain, unless you are requesting a JSONP response. This is a security feature in all browsers. Google for 'Same origin policy' and 'Cross site scripting' for more info.

The workaround is to use a server-side proxy to request the data from the external domain, then use jQuery to query your local proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `jquery/demo_ajax_json.js` with `your file name.js`

i.e.,   `$.getJSON("http://w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js", function (result)` with   `$.getJSON("path/your file", function (result) {`