# Can not fetch json content from remote web address

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to fetch the data from http://status.mojang.com/check but i am not getting any data back. However i am getting the data in my response tab (google chrome)

I am running it on a webserver to test it and i also tried local.

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("//status.mojang.com/check?jsoncallback=?", function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

[image: The network tab]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @bfavaretto If it was a same-origin problem, wouldn't it NOT send the request and NOT get data back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery getJSON Not Working Cross Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038862/jquery-getjson-not-working-cross-site)

Comment: No, the request is sent anyway, but you don't get the data back.

Comment: It's a parse error, it's just JSON, not JSONP, the callback is never added as it doesn't seem like it's supported.

Comment: @LeeMeador sometimes the request will actually come back fine but the browser will refuse to pass it through, due to the same-origin policy. I've had this happen a few times. Chrome especially seems to do this.

Comment: @Maxim Please confirm, is it cross-site? If it's not, I'll retract my close vote. If it is, you must use JSONP, and the server must support it (or CORS).

Comment: If OP puts a failure function and message in there and it doesn't fails and it doesn't succeed that would seem to indicate a same-origin problem as opposed to merely a failure somewhere. (Like is parsing the JSON.) Is the JSON valid?

Comment: @bfavaretto it is cross-site. I haven't solved it still.

Comment: i also tried to use the REST client on google chrome, that plugin is able to retrieve the data that i need. However i need it with javascript on my html page not in a chrome plugin.

Comment: If it's cross-site and the server does not support JSONP or CORS, you can't do it with JavaScript. As a workaround you can create a server-side script that fetches that url, and use your own server as a proxy for that content (then your get it from your own server with ajax).

Comment: but why is the data in the networking tab ?

Comment: See the comment by Bucky24 above, apparently that's a Chrome glitch.

Comment: Okay, if you want to tell it in an answer, i'll be happy to mark it as accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery help page (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/),

```
This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

As you are accessing an external URL, you'll need to send your request as a jsonp call in order to get around the access-control-allow-origin headers. That means `dataType` needs to be "jsonp"

Comment: JSONP - is json answer with callback function. And this not solve problem if he don't have access to `status.mojang.com` server. More good solution is CORS

Comment: You seem to have misread the posting. His browser is making the request prefectly fine, but is refusing to pass the data along to his javascript code. JSONP will solve this issue, as he does have access to the server.

Comment: The jQuery docs says it sees the 'callback' part and adjusts accordingly. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and then search in the page for "callback=" to read it.

Comment: I have tried this already but i get the same problem: i see the data in returned in the network tab but i can't access it in javascript